# mpirun retaining redirected stdout

Tags: mpi, stdout

I am running in a cluster. I tried to run my executable with 4 different forms:

1. In serial, with

   ```
   myexec
   ```

   This starts giving output in `stdout` right away, as expected.
2. In serial, redirecting `stdout` and `stderr`, with

   ```
   myexec > out-err.log 2>&1
   ```

   This starts giving output in `out-err.log` right away, as expected (verified with `cat out-err.log` in another terminal).
3. In parallel, with

   ```
   mpirun -n 2 myexec
   ```

   This starts giving output in `stdout` right away, as expected.
4. In parallel, redirecting `stdout` and `stderr`, with

   ```
   mpirun -n 2 myexec > out-err.log 2>&1
   ```

   This retains output until job is finished (due to completion or time allowance).

**Is there any way of having stdout/stderr "flushed" at runtime in case 4, so I can check `out-err.log`?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known feature/issue with redirection in mpi.
I found how to solve this:

1. Add `export OMPI_MCA_opal_event_include=poll` in `~/.bashrc`, or
2. Add `opal_event_include=poll` in `~/.openmpi/mca-params.conf` (create the dir and/or file if they do not exist).

The sources used to get info are:

https://www.cfd-online.com/Forums/openfoam-installation/162664-openfoam-2-4-0-openmpi-epoll-warning-parallel-job.html

https://github.com/open-mpi/ompi/issues/341

https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v2.0/man1/mpirun.1.php#sect20